# Import from a ParcelJS bundle

Tags: javascript, import, importerror, parceljs

**The Context:**

I have created a library with an index resource like this:

```
import {X} from '...'
import {Y} from '...'
import {Z} from '...'

export {X, Y, Z}
```

As it can be seen, this file collect all public resources of the library and expose them as accesible entry points according to the ES6 Modules standard. When I use ParcelJs to create a bundle named `my-library.js` from the index file, all works fine.

**The Problem:**

Now, I want to use from the browser the library so I create index.html with the following script (Please note that this code is not part of my project and not is my interest to be included in the bundle. It only works as a temporal test):

```
<script type="module">
 import {X} from './my-library.js'
 console.log (X)
</script>
```

As a result, the console emit the following error message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './my-library.js' does
not provide an export named 'X'
```

What is the problem? Can ParcelJS be used to bundle a library according to ES6 specification in order to be invoked latter on using import sentences from an external script?

Answer (score 0):

As of today (August 2020), this feature is only available in beta in Parcel2. Here is how you could get what you want working:

1. Install Parcel2: `npm i -g parcel@next`
2. In your project, install Babel core: `npm i @babel/core --save-dev`
3. In your `package.json` add the following config:

```js
  "main": "dist/legacy/index.js",
  "module": "dist/modern/index.js",
  "targets": {
    "module": {
      "engines": {
        "browsers": [
          "last 1 Chrome version"
        ]
      }
    },
    "main": {
      "engines": {
        "browsers": [
          "> 0.25%"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

4. Build your code: `parcel build index.js`

The bundle under `dist/legacy/index.js` uses CommonJS while the bundle under `dist/modern/index.js` uses the ESM syntax.

> NOTE: Another alternative to bundle JS packages to multiple targets is [Microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle).